# Run the application on thread after a specific duration

Tags: ios

I am running a web service to refresh my application, but I want refresh my after 1 hr and I am using the code for running the thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// post an NSNotification that loading has started
for (x = 0; x++ ; x < numberOfRequests) {
    // create the NSURLRequest for this loop iteration
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&response
                                                     error:&error];
    // do something with the data, response, error, etc
}
// post an NSNotification that loading is finished
});
```

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: You want suggestion regarding refreshing your app after 1hr?

Comment: Why don't you use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and call web service from this? You can put your delay time in it.

Comment: write the above code in some `method`, and call that `method` using an `NSTimer` with interval for 1 hr.

Comment: See prachi, you can use a timer, and once 60minutes are done, call the  method and reset the timerCounter.

Comment: @PiyushDubey: She want repeatedly, but `perSel:afterDelay:` will be just once.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Sir: Then she can use `NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` and set 'Repeats' Yes.

Comment: @PiyushDubey: Exactly !!! Happy to see *YES*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a timer say as follows:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3600.0 target:self selector:@selector(callWebService) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Note:** the `3600.0` represents the equivalent of 1 hour in seconds.

Then you may envelope your code in a method such as `callWebService` which is what I have used:

```
- (void)callWebService
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // post an NSNotification that loading has started
        for (x = 0; x++ ; x < numberOfRequests) {
            // create the NSURLRequest for this loop iteration
            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];
            // do something with the data, response, error, etc
        }
    // post an NSNotification that loading is finished
    });
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:-
`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3600.0 target:self selector:@selector(triggerTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`
 And call your web service in this method:-

```
- (void)triggerTimer
{
    // Call your web service from here.
    // Refresh here.
}
```